# Error in downloading zipped parent folder from app using Spring Boot and Java script

Tags: ajax, spring-boot

I am working on Spring Boot application where I need to provide download zipped report files feature. In order to do that I am converting zipped report files to byte array and then trying to send it at the browser side. I am able to download the zipped report file but when I try to extract it gives an error message that 'The Compressed zipped folder is invalid.' Please find the code snippet below:

Server Side Code:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadResult", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/zip" )
    public byte[] downloadResult(@RequestBody ResultParamsVO resultParamsVO, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        byte[] result = null;
        try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

 

            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            String user = auth.getPrincipal().toString();
            String testType = null;
            if (session.getAttribute("testType") != null) {
                testType = session.getAttribute("testType").toString();
            }
            result = jobService.downloadResult(resultParamsVO, testType, user);

 

            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=resultDownload1.zip");

 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error in getResult() for job id - " + resultParamsVO.getJobId(), e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Browser Side Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/downloadResult",
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify(resultParamsVO),
          success: function(result) {
             
              var downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([result], {type: "application/zip"}));
              var a = document.createElement("a");
              a.href = downloadUrl;
              a.download = "resultDownload.zip";
              document.body.appendChild(a);
              a.click();
          }
        });
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it working from browser?

Comment: No. It is not working from browser.

Comment: Then there is some issue in java code.

Comment: I can download text file from the same code. So, I think issue is with only .zip files.

Comment: Oh! Then may be zip issue.